# Image not resizing relative to its parent

Tags: html, css

I have a contain which is just a Grid based container looking something like:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}
```

This container is a child container to a parent, which basically has a `height: 100%` where the true height is defined by another parent, which is set to the height of the screen minus some padding. So in some way a fixed viewport depending on screen size. I understand that if I don't use `overflow: auto` or something on my `container` or the others, if enough items are put into e.g. the container it will eventually expand to more than the intended size. However, since the item that is put in the `1fr` grid of the `container`, I actually just thought that images would contain themselves, since they can pretty much scale as much as possible.

So the thing in the `1fr` grid is the following:

```
picture {
    display: grid;
    place-content: center;

    img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        object-fit: contain;
    }
}
```

So the HTML setup is something like this (there are a bunch of other stuff, but this is the main stuff):

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Some text</p>
        <picture>
            <img src="myimg.jpg" />
        </picture
    </div>
 </div>
```

The issue is that the images have some true size. So with this, and a big enough screen, there will be no issue since the images aren't screen size huge. So this actually just expands the image a wide as it truly is. However, when I make my screen smaller, the image dimensions are becoming larger than the size of the container, and instead of the image just adjusting to the container (which will grow/shrink according to screen size) it just remains the same, and will eventually push the rest of the content out of the viewport. I have tried with different configurations, but none seem to really work.

I don't know if it can even be done with just pure CSS, but it's kind of annoying me.

Comment: with pure CSS you can't nest selectors. `object-fit` has to be used on the container

Comment: «However, when I make my screen smaller, the image dimensions are becoming larger than the size of the container». What do you mean? I have checked your code above, don't see the problem.